# In OVS's fast-failover mode, can watch-port be pointed to the CONTROLLER port?

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

I have tried using this manually, and adding a rule that sets the `watch-port` to be `CONTROLLER`, but this does not seem to work when I try it. The purpose of this will be to redirect rules if connection to a controller is down.

Is anyone aware of whether this should work, or there are plans of making this feature? I have not found anything personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. A `watch-port` needs to be the number of one of the switch's ports.